# Get variable value or run function from different Object - Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, swift2, protocols

I am trying to: get the value of a few variables, as well as run some functions which live in Object A, all from Object B.

I have tried for hours now to make it work with delegates and protocols. No luck.

I can't do something like this:

```
 var delegate: MyDelegate = ViewController()
```

Because it seems to create a new instance of ViewController. And I want the values from the instance that is already running.

I also cannot do:

```
var delegate: MyDelegate?
```

Because the ViewController object never responds. So I get a nil anytime I call delegate?.somefunction()

I don't want a segue between screens. I just need to start a function from another object.

I bet this is an easy fix. I just can't get it. Thanks for your help.

Some of my code:

```
class PauseButtonView: NSView{
   var delegate: PauseButtonDelegate?
   ...
   var result = delegate?.startFunction()
}

protocol PauseButtonDelegate {
    func startFunction() -> String
}



  class ViewController: NSViewController, PauseButtonDelegate {
      func startFunction() -> String {
         let myString = "Hello World!"
         return myString
      }
}
```

Comment: In order to start a method of another object you must have a reference to that object. How is your class going to get a hold of the running view controller object?

Comment: Show us the creation of Object A and B please. Also you might want a weak delegate unless you want strong reference cycles.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want either classes to have a reference to the other, you could use internal notifications to communicate between them:

```
  // in your PauseButtonView
  let object:[String:AnyObject] = [ "aParameter" : 42 ]
  let startNotification = NSNotification(name: "startFunction:", object: object) 
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(startNotification)

  // in the view controller
  func startFunction(notification:NSNotification)
  {
     let object = notification.object as? [String:AnyObject]
     //...
  }
```